# How to check whether a file is present or not using file watcher jobs in Autosys

Tags: autosys

There is arequirement which we need to fulfill using file watchers. I was wondering whether we can use file watchers to detect file successfully if the file is present before the file watcher job is started.

Comment: The sole purpose of File Watcher job is to watch for a file. Why would you use another job before the FW job itself.

Comment: @Piyush Thanks for your reply what I was asking is let's say we don't know file arrival time we only know that a batch file will run if the file arrives . let's say the file arrives at 5am and the batch file runs at 9 am so can I schedule the file watcher job at 9am rather than 5am means can we check presence of that particular file using file watcher?

Answer (score 1):

JIL:

```
insert_job: APP_BATCH_FW_JOB
job_type: FW
machine: some@hostname
days_of_week: mon,tue,wed,thru,fri
start_times: "09:00"
watch_file: /app/input/infeed.txt
watch_interval: 60 # every 60 sec it would check for the file
term_run_time: 15 # after 15 mins the job would be terminated if file is not found

insert_job: APP_BATCH_START_JOB
job_type: CMD
machine: some@hostname
command: bash /app/script/start.bash
condition: SUCCESS(APP_BATCH_FW_JOB)
```

At 09:00 the file watcher job would start, and search for the file for 15 mins.

- If file is found, the following batch start job would start.
- If file is not found, the FW jon would be in terminated status by
  09:15

[User Manual](https://ftpdocs.broadcom.com/cadocs/0/CA%20Workload%20Automation%20AE%20Release%2011%203%206%20-%20Public%20Access-ENU/Bookshelf_Files/PDF/WA_AE_User_ENU.pdf)

Comment: Hi Piyush thanks for your answer . One question will this work if the file watcher job is started after file has reached it's destination?